# Can you name a single popular database that doesn't support LIMIT statement?

Tags: sql, database, limit

Drupal uses `db_query_range()` for the reason that not all databases support `LIMIT`,

can you name a few?

Answer (score 7):

DB2, MSSQL, Oracle, and Informix all do not support LIMIT.  As a matter of fact, it's not in the SQL standard.  (The standard one is "FETCH FIRST" indeed)

Here is a good source for SQL comparisons: http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft SQL Server does not support `LIMIT`. It supports the `TOP` statement which can be used to accomplish similar things. The primary limitation with `TOP` is the inability to specify an offset.

Comment: Yeah, would be good if TOP worked with OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...) too

Answer (score 2):

ms sql, oracle.

and actually `LIMIT` doesn't exists in ANSI SQL '92 which all modern databases should follow. so currently it's just an unnecessary extension/syntactic sugar/specific sql dialect

Answer (score 2):

DB2, Oracle, and MS SQL Server do not support the `LIMIT` clause.

Google for `<database name> LIMIT`, and you'll get to know the equivalent supported clause for that database, or whether `LIMIT` itself is supported.

Answer (score 0):

On the flip side, ANSI-92 SQL provides the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function for achieving this, which is supported on many databases. See [SELECT (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29) on Wikipedia.