# How do I get the userID which is in most rows? SQL problem

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures

I am unable to move forward and can't find the appropriate example using Google Search. Maybe I just don’t know how to phrase my search. Anyway, it is probably simple, and I just don’t know how to get it.

How do I get the userID which is in most rows (the user that raised most tickets)?

[image]

Any tip or link to a similar solution would be really helpful.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159928/sql-displaying-entries-that-are-the-max-of-a-count

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for as the question is very vague. It would help to post sample data with expected results.

But, from what I understand, find the UserID with more tickets raised. The below query would give you the count of users with most on top.

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(*)
  FROM Table
 GROUP BY UserId
 ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: That query will just return the count of all rows.

Comment: Is that standard indentation for SELECT - FROM - ORDER BY?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it. Group counts by user ID, order by counts descending, and only take the first one.

```sql
SELECT
userID,
COUNT(*)
FROM unknown_table_name
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

---

EDIT: Adding disclaimer that `LIMIT` would not be supported on [DB2, MSSQL, Oracle, and Informix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832050/7214439)

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Good point, `LIMIT` would not be supported in [DB2, MSSQL, Oracle, and Informix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832050/7214439).

Comment: It would be even better if you listed the products supporting LIMIT. (And that weird GROUP BY ordinal position syntax...)

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick

```
SELECT t1.UserId, 
(
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM {table} t2 
 WHERE t2.UserId = t1.UserId
) counter 
FROM {table} t1 
 GROUP BY t1.UserId 
 ORDER BY counter 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

We count all the rows in which UserId appears, sort them in descending order and filter out the rest.

Comment: No need to combine a correlated subquery with group by.